# Why are the magnetization vectors circumferential in this scenario?

Tags: electromagnetism

Please refer to the figure below, taken from Griffiths' electrodynamics book.

[image]

In the figure is a copper wire carrying a current *I*, which gives rise to a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$. No other information is given. Below is Griffith's argument for the directions of the magnetization vector $\mathbf{M}$ and the field $\mathbf{H} = \frac{1}{\mu_0}\mathbf{B} - \mathbf{M}$:

1. Copper is diamagnetic so the dipoles within the wire will line up opposite to the field, resulting in a bound volume current $\mathbf{J}_b$ runnning antiparallel to *I*, and a bound surface current $\mathbf{K}_b$ parallel to *I*.
2. Because all these currents are longitudinal, so $\mathbf{B}, \mathbf{M},$ and therefore $\mathbf{H}$ are circumferential.

I understand argument $1$, but not sure about argument $2$:

1. I understand that $\mathbf{B}$ must be circumferential.
2. If $\mathbf{M}$ is circumferential then obviously $\mathbf{H}$ must be circumferential.

However, **my question is:** Why is $\mathbf{M}$ circumferential in this scenario? The fact that all the currents are longitudinal doesn't seem to have any connection with the direction of $\mathbf{M}$.

Comment: If we assume copper is a linear medium, then $\mathbf{M}$ must be along $\mathbf{B}$.

Comment: Thank you! The author didn't even bother mentioning his assumption in the example, which made me so confused... Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: I just checked the book. The chapter talking about linear media is *after* this example. I don't know why he did that...

Comment: Well, it may be that this example has different reasoning behind it. Linear media were just the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: All of Griffith's arguments are posted in my question. Do you think you can give an alternative explanation that does not rely on the linearity of the medium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, Griffiths might be assuming that copper is a linear medium; as such, $\mathbf{M}$ is required to be along $\mathbf{B}$, meaning that $\mathbf{M}$ is also circumferential. Since we also know copper is diamagnetic, $\mathbf{M}$ must be circulating in the opposite direction of $\mathbf{B}$.